# Matlab - GUI change axes size

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

How do I change sizes of axes (min - max limits).

In my GUI I have used "Axes" object and I want to set manual size of X and Y axes through "Edit text" field.

This is picture of my GUI:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `callback` on your `uielement` to execute a  function that contains code like this:

`set(axesHandle, 'Xlim', newXLim, 'YLim', newYLim);`

For more information see the official docs: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/examples-programming-gui-components.html?s_tid=doc_12b